# Prepend string to each key in JSON file

Tags: bash, shell-script, json

I have a JSON file I'm reading into a bash script and would like to prepend a fixed string to each key.

json_file:

```json
{"key_1": 12, "key_2": 34, "key_3": 56}
```

What's the cleanest way I can update this data by prepending the string `x_` to each key?

For example,

```json
{"x_key_1": 12, "x_key_2": 34, "x_key_3": 56}
```

Comment: Is that your correct json format? All key-values in the same line?

Comment: Sorry, yeah this is all in one line. It was a json.dump() call from Python. All values are integers.

Comment: @user546158 If it came from a Python script, then it would possibly be better to make this change in the script rather than as a post-processing step.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a JSON parser such as `jq` to parse your JSON file. The advantage of this is that valid JSON can be handled regardless of its shape:

```
jq 'with_entries(.key |= "x_" + .)' <file.json
```

Input

```
{"key_1": 12, "key_2": 34, "key_3": 56}
```

Output

```
{
  "x_key_1": 12,
  "x_key_2": 34,
  "x_key_3": 56
}
```

You can keep the JSON on one line with `jq -c …`:

```
{"x_key_1":12,"x_key_2":34,"x_key_3":56}
```

This solution is shown as an example in the documentation for `jq` - see `man jq` and search for `with_entries` - but as it's a reference document it can be hard to find things you don't know how to describe.

Answer (score 0):

If your json format is in one-line then the following should work:

```bash
sed -i 's/"\([^"]*\)":/"x_\1":/g' json_file.json
```

If your json format looks like this:

```json
{
   "key_1": 1, 
   "key_2": "v2", 
   "key_3": 3
}
```

You could use the `sed` command above but you also can use the following `sed` which is a little easier:

```bash
sed -i 's/"\(.*\)":/"x_\1":/'  json_file.json
```

**Note:** The solution above works well if you just have numbers or strings that don't have the following pattern:

```json
{ "key_1": "\"Sale\": foobar" }
// Or
{ "\"key_1\"": "\"Sale\": foobar" } // I think  this case is less common
```

So the best way to edit the keys correctly is by using the [roaima's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/721962/414186).
I tried another possible solution with `sed` (but I'm not sure if there are other cases where it might fail).
If your json file looks like this:

```json
{"key_1": "\"Sale\": foobar", "key_2": "\"3\":", "key_3": 56}
// Or maybe
{"key_1": "\"Sale:sale\": foobar", "key_2": "\"3\":", "key_3": 56}
```

you can try using:

```bash
sed -i 's/"\([^"\][^"\]*\)":/"x_\1":/g' json_file.json
```

However the command above will fail if the json file looks like this:

```json
{"\"key_1\"": "\"Sale:\": foobar", "key_2": "\"3\":", "key_3": 56}
// If the json keys  have \"somekey\" as their keys then the sed command will fail. 
// So using sed for this task might be a little tricky for avoiding these problems.
```

Comment: Thank you, the first command solved my problem!

Comment: I'm not sure why this was down-voted but no problem. However if it's for `v1`, `v2` and `v3` I know are not valid and they must be numbers or between `"` but the OP had specified those values (the question was edited after my answer). The command works either the values are number or not. Maybe I did not consider some cases where the command will not work as expected.

Comment: If one of the _values_ is the JSON string `"\"Sale\": foobar"`, it would be modified into `"\"x_Sale\": foobar"` by your `sed` command.

Comment: @Kusalananda thank you! I appreciate the comment! I had no idea about that case. I'll try to change the sed command anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the question in the title literally, the following appends some user-provided string to all keys in the input document recursively:

```bash
jq --arg prefix x_ '
    walk(
        if type == "object" then 
            with_entries(.key = $prefix + .key)
        else . end
    )' file
```

The key is updated similarly to what's done in [roaima's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/721962/116858), but without using the update operator. The prefix string is also given on the command line instead of being a hard-coded string.

Test run:

```bash
$ cat file
{
  "key_1": 12,
  "key_2": 34,
  "key_3": [
    {
      "key_1": "{\"key_A\":123}",
      "key_2": 34,
      "key_3": 56
    },
    {
      "key_1": "{\"key_A\":123}",
      "key_2": 34,
      "key_3": 56
    }
  ]
}
```

```bash
$ jq --arg prefix x_ 'walk(if type == "object" then with_entries(.key = $prefix + .key) else . end)' file
{
  "x_key_1": 12,
  "x_key_2": 34,
  "x_key_3": [
    {
      "x_key_1": "{\"key_A\":123}",
      "x_key_2": 34,
      "x_key_3": 56
    },
    {
      "x_key_1": "{\"key_A\":123}",
      "x_key_2": 34,
      "x_key_3": 56
    }
  ]
}
```